# accordion not working using codeigniter ajax pagination

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I am using Ajax pagination which is working fine and displaying data in accordion. For the first time, the accordion is working fine, but when I click on any button (next, previous, 1,2 or 3), the data is retrieved and is displayed in accordion but, accordion item is not expanding(as it is for the first time).

Here's the code,

For controller

```
function productandservice() {
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "home/productandservice";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->user->prod_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 2;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = ' ';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->user->fetch_prod($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();


    if($this->input->post('ajax')) {
        $this->load->view('ciajaxpagination',$data);
    } 
    else {
        $data['dropdown'] = $this->user->getcategory();
        $this->load->view('user/product-service',$data);
    }

    //$data['view_file'] = 'user/product-service';
    //$data['result'] = $result;
}
```

code for view (main Productandservices page)

```
<div class="span12">
<div class="accordion" id="ajaxdata">
<?php

 foreach($results as $data) {
    echo "<div class='accordion-item'>";
    echo "<a class='accordion-item-toggle' href='#' style='color:#fff'>".$data->name."</a>";
    echo "<div class='accordion-item-content fixed' style='display: none;'>";
    echo "<div class='span4'>";
    echo "<img src='_content/index/slider/slider-3-p1.png' alt='sample product-service'></div>";
    echo "<div class='8'>";
    echo "Description:<p>".$data->description."</p>";
    echo "Keywords:<p>".$data->keywords."</p>";
    //echo $data->name . " - " . $data->description . "<br>";
    echo "<p><a class='btn btn-orange' id='btnedit-product' href='#edit-product'>Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class='btn btn-orange' href='#'>Delete</a></p>";
    echo "</div></div><div>";
}
?>    
<div class="accordion-item" >
    <a class="accordion-item-toggle" href="#" style="color:#fff"> Product/Service 1</a>
    <div class="accordion-item-content fixed" style="display: none;">
        <div class="span4">
            <img src="_content/index/slider/slider-3-p1.png" alt="sample product-service">
        </div>
        <div class="8">Description:<p> Duis sed quam risus. Vivamus ultrices et risus id hendrerit. Etiam quam diam, imperdiet ac euismod in, scelerisque vitae libero. Nullam vitae tempus est. Sed ullamcorper, odio a egestas porta, urna urna elementum dui, at lacinia.</p>
        Keywords : <p>keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4, keyword5</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-orange" id="btnedit-product" href="#edit-product">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-orange" href="#">Delete</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pagination" id="ajax_pagingsearc">
    <p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and the code for ciajaxpagination.php

```
<?php
foreach($results as $data) {
    echo "<div class='accordion-item'>";
    echo "<a class='accordion-item-toggle' href='#' style='color:#fff'>".$data->name."</a>";
    echo "<div class='accordion-item-content fixed' style='display: none;'>";
    echo "<div class='span4'>";
    echo "<img src='_content/index/slider/slider-3-p1.png' alt='sample product-service'></div>";
    echo "<div class='8'>";
    echo "Description:<p>".$data->description."</p>";
    echo "Keywords:<p>".$data->keywords."</p>";
    //echo $data->name . " - " . $data->description . "<br>";
    echo "<p><a class='btn btn-orange' id='btnedit-product' href='#edit-product'>Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class='btn btn-orange' href='#'>Delete</a></p>";
    echo "</div></div></div>";
}
?>
<div class="pagination" id="ajax_pagingsearc">
    <p><?php echo $links; ?></p>
</div>
```

this is the function that is used for calling data through ajax

```
$(function() {
      applyPagination();

      function applyPagination() {
        $("#ajax_pagingsearc a").click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr("href");

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "ajax=1",
            url: url,
           success: function(msg) {

              $("#ajaxdata").html(msg);
              applyPagination();
            }
          });
        return false;
        });
      }
    });
```

you can see the live [demo](http://www.foodcognics.com/productandservice),
 (check the second tab products and services list)

Please help me solve this problem as soon as possible

Note: first login using given credetials

username: vishal@gmail.com / password : password

Only then the products of that user will be loaded.

Comment: error for link:Unable to load the requested class: ajax_pagination

Comment: I was doing some changes. fixed that please check.  NOte: first login using given credetials username: vishal@gmail.com password : password

Only then the products of that user will be loaded.

Comment: try this add your accordion code after  $("#ajaxdata").html(msg);
              applyPagination(); in ajax success. I am not sure but give it try.

Comment: ok. let me try it...

Comment: @mokNathal, that didn't work... any other idea?